# Get all UIViews affected by moving another UIView above them

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview

I have a `UIScrollView` that contains a number of draggable `UIViews` with different sizes, mostly square. These `UIViews` snap to a 6-column grid on the screen.

When a `UIView` (let's say its size is 132x132) snaps into position and another `UIView's` frame intersects with the first `UIView` frame, the second is supposed to move below the first, either by the full or half the height of the first `UIView` (depends on where the `UIViews` intersect). I got this working by using `CGRectIntersectsRect`, as well as `CGRectGetMaXY` and `CGRectGetMinY` to calculate the required moving distance.

However, there is also the possibility of a third or even more `UIViews` below the already affected UIView which might also have to be moved. My problem here is that I am not able to

a) get all affected `UIViews` below the moved `UIView` (not the snapped `UIView`) in the correct order (ordered by their Y origin)
b) move `UIViews` based on the `UIView` above them ONLY without being affected by the `UIView` that snaps into place (even though moving distance might be the same).

My current attempt is to get one `UIView` that intersects with the moved `UIView` after snapping, adding the `UIView` and the required moving distance as a dictionary to an array, and then adding other `UIViews` below it using recursion. Sometimes however, `UIViews` are moved incorrectly due to their order in the view hierarchy, or they aren't even moved at all.

Here is an example:

- UIView A with frame = `0 0; 269 132`
- UIView B with frame = `0 205.5; 63.5 63.5`
- UIView C with frame = `137 137; 132 132` that snaps into `0 0; 132 132`
- Border spacing is 5 pixels

When `UIView` C snaps into place, UIView A is supposed to move to `0 137; 269 132`, because the required moving distance is the full height of UIView C + the border spacing. But moving `UIView` A to its new position affects `UIView` B too, which is then moved to `0 274; 63.5 63.5`, half the height of `UIView` A + the border spacing, removing the space between `UIView` A and B.

Here is another example:

- UIView A with frame = `0 0; 269 132`
- UIView B with frame = `0 205.5; 63.5 63.5`
- UIView C with frame = `0 274; 269 269` that snaps into `0 68.5; 269 269`

When `UIView` C moves into place, UIView A is moved to `0 274; 269 132` which then affects `UIView` B and moves that to `0 411; 63.5 63.5`, removing the space that was between `UIView` A and B before.

Comment: In your first example, do you mean to say your UIView A's frame size is changing from 269,132 to 132,132? Is that correct? I'm assuming those are width/height of the frame.

Comment: In your second example, after UIView C moves into place, and UIView A moves, then C and A are overlapping?

Comment: UIView sizes aren't changing. That was a mistake and I've fixed it. In the second example, when UIView C moves into place, it overlaps with both A and B and therefore need to be moved down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to setup a first-in, first-out stack. The algorithm will look something like this (not valid Obj-C code!):

```
move viewC
[stack addObject: viewC]
while stack.isEmpty == false {
    current = stack[0]
    remove current from stack
    for view in allViews {
        if view != current and view needs to move because of current's position {
            [stack addObject: view]
            move view to correct position
        }
    }
}
```

The above would first move viewC to its new position, then scan through all the views, other than viewC, and move them out from under viewC if necessary. Each view that is moved will be added to the stack.

Then it would go through all the views that were moved because of viewC's new position and check to see if any views that weren't yet moved have to be moved because of *that* view's new position. And so on...

-- edit --

After reflection, I don't think you need to keep track of what views have been visited. I updated the algorithm to remove that step.

Comment: The above is a variation on Dijkstra's algorithm for path-finding, but repurposed for view moving.

Comment: This algorithm is working really well. Far better than anything I've tried. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

This is the Objective-C implementation I'm using, based on Daniel T.'s answer and his pseudo code. I accepted his answer because he provided the actual solution. This is just for reference.

```
- (void)moveAffectedViewsForView:(UIView*)movedView {
    NSMutableArray* stack = [NSMutableArray new];
    [stack addObject:movedView];

    while ([stack count] > 0) {
        UIView* current = [stack objectAtIndex:0];
        [stack removeObject:current];

        for (UIView* view in [self subviews]) {
            if (view != current && CGRectIntersectsRect(current.frame, view.frame)) {
                [stack addObject:view];

                CGFloat moveDistance = (CGRectGetMaxY(current.frame) - CGRectGetMinY(view.frame)) + 5;
                [view setFrame:CGRectOffset(view.frame, 0, moveDistance)];
             }
        }
    }
}
```